# Variables aren't evaluated in post build event

Tags: visual-studio-2012, post-build-event

I'm trying to run this post build event in Visual Studio 2012 :

```
set n=$(ConfigurationName)    
set n=%n:~0,7%    
echo %n%    
if "%n%" == "Release" copy "$(TargetPath)" "$(ProjectDir)..\..\DLLs\$(TargetFileName)"
```

And here is the output :

```
set n=RELEASE MYSERVER    
set n=%n:~0,7%    
echo %n%    
if "%n%" == "Release" copy "C:\MyFolder\bin\RELEASE MYSERVER\MyDLL.dll" "C:\MyFolder\..\..\DLLs\MyDLL.dll"    
RELEASE
```

As you can see, the "echo %n%" correctly output "RELEASE", but in the "if" statement, %n% is not evaluated.

Why this?
How can I do?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have to turn delayed expansion.

Comment: I tried by using the following :
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

but it doesn't work :(

Comment: OK, sorry, the problem didn't come from the %n% that was not evaluated, but from the test done.

The "if" statement is case sensitive. To have this batch work correctly an case insentive test must be done with "if /I"

Comment: Post that as the answer :)